# Can not set SelectionChangedCommand.Command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, prism

I try to use this xaml, to apply an event to command binding:

```
 <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="xRadGridView"

                            prismcommands:SelectionChangedCommand.Command="{Binding SelectPersonCommand}"

                             ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
        </telerik:RadGridView>
```

I get the error:

> 'SelectionChangedCommand.Command' property is read-only and cannot be
>   set from markup.

I can bind to   prismcommands:RowEditEndedCommand.Command with no problem.
Is there any chance to bind to  SelectionChangedCommand.Command?

I use the same PrismCommands in a Silverlight project and it works there.

```
namespace RadEventToCommand.WPF.PrismCommands
{
    public class RowEditEndedCommandBehavior : CommandBehaviorBase<RadGridView>
    {
        public RowEditEndedCommandBehavior(RadGridView gridView)
            : base(gridView)
        {
            gridView.RowEditEnded +=new EventHandler<GridViewRowEditEndedEventArgs>(gridView_RowEditEnded);
        }

        void gridView_RowEditEnded(object sender, GridViewRowEditEndedEventArgs e)
        {
            CommandParameter = e;

            ExecuteCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
namespace RadEventToCommand.WPF.PrismCommands
{
    public static class SelectionChangedCommand
    {
        private static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionChangedCommandBehaviorProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "SelectionChangedCommandBehavior",
            typeof(SelectionChangedCommandBehavior),
            typeof(SelectionChangedCommand),
            null);

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Command",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(SelectionChangedCommand),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnSetCommandCallback));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "CommandParameter",
           typeof(object),
           typeof(SelectionChangedCommand),
           new PropertyMetadata(OnSetCommandParameterCallback));

        public static ICommand GetCommand(RadGridView gridView)
        {
            return gridView.GetValue(CommandProperty) as ICommand;
        }

        public static void SetCommandParameter(RadGridView gridView, object parameter)
        {
            gridView.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, parameter);
        }

        public static object GetCommandParameter(RadGridView gridView)
        {
            return gridView.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        private static void OnSetCommandCallback
            (DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadGridView gridView = dependencyObject as RadGridView;
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                SelectionChangedCommandBehavior behavior = GetOrCreateBehavior(gridView);
                behavior.Command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
            }
        }

        private static void OnSetCommandParameterCallback
            (DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadGridView gridView = dependencyObject as RadGridView;
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                SelectionChangedCommandBehavior behavior = GetOrCreateBehavior(gridView);
                behavior.CommandParameter = e.NewValue;
            }
        }

        private static SelectionChangedCommandBehavior GetOrCreateBehavior(RadGridView gridView)
        {
            SelectionChangedCommandBehavior behavior =
                gridView.GetValue(SelectionChangedCommandBehaviorProperty) as SelectionChangedCommandBehavior;
            if (behavior == null)
            {
                behavior = new SelectionChangedCommandBehavior(gridView);
                gridView.SetValue(SelectionChangedCommandBehaviorProperty, behavior);
            }
            return behavior;
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
namespace RadEventToCommand.WPF.PrismCommands
{
    public class RowEditEndedCommandBehavior : CommandBehaviorBase<RadGridView>
    {
        public RowEditEndedCommandBehavior(RadGridView gridView)
            : base(gridView)
        {
            gridView.RowEditEnded +=new EventHandler<GridViewRowEditEndedEventArgs>(gridView_RowEditEnded);
        }

        void gridView_RowEditEnded(object sender, GridViewRowEditEndedEventArgs e)
        {
            CommandParameter = e;

            ExecuteCommand();
        }
    }
```

}

--

```
namespace RadEventToCommand.WPF.PrismCommands
{
    public static class RowEditEndedCommand
    {
        private static DependencyProperty RowEditEndedCommandBehaviorProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "RowEditEndedCommandBehavior",
            typeof(RowEditEndedCommandBehavior),
            typeof(RowEditEndedCommand),
            null);

        public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Command",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(RowEditEndedCommand),
            new PropertyMetadata(OnSetCommandCallback));

        public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
           "CommandParameter",
           typeof(object),
           typeof(RowEditEndedCommand),
           new PropertyMetadata(OnSetCommandParameterCallback));

        public static ICommand GetCommand(RadGridView gridView)
        {
            return gridView.GetValue(CommandProperty) as ICommand;
        }

        public static void SetCommand(RadGridView gridView, object parameter)
        {
            gridView.SetValue(CommandProperty, parameter);
        }

        public static void SetCommandParameter(RadGridView gridView, object parameter)
        {
            gridView.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, parameter);
        }

        public static object GetCommandParameter(RadGridView gridView)
        {
            return gridView.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        }

        private static void OnSetCommandCallback
            (DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadGridView gridView = dependencyObject as RadGridView;
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                RowEditEndedCommandBehavior behavior = GetOrCreateBehavior(gridView);
                behavior.Command = e.NewValue as ICommand;
            }
        }

        private static void OnSetCommandParameterCallback
            (DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadGridView gridView = dependencyObject as RadGridView;
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                RowEditEndedCommandBehavior behavior = GetOrCreateBehavior(gridView);
                behavior.CommandParameter = e.NewValue;
            }
        }

        private static RowEditEndedCommandBehavior GetOrCreateBehavior(RadGridView gridView)
        {
            RowEditEndedCommandBehavior behavior =
                gridView.GetValue(RowEditEndedCommandBehaviorProperty) as RowEditEndedCommandBehavior;
            if (behavior == null)
            {
                behavior = new RowEditEndedCommandBehavior(gridView);
                gridView.SetValue(RowEditEndedCommandBehaviorProperty, behavior);
            }
            return behavior;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the source for the behavior copied over from a Silverlight project. It worked there. For some reason in WPF I need the additional method in SelectionChangedCommand

```
   public static void SetCommand(RadGridView gridView, object parameter)
        {
            gridView.SetValue(CommandProperty, parameter);
        }
```

I copied the code over to check if I could use a common codebase for Silverlight and WPF.

Answer (score 0):

For the RadGridView, we are using the Interaction Triggers. The below code works for us.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItemChangedCommand}"/>
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```